# TempData & Redirect for Errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller action in my project that has a situation where it needs to display an error message to the user under certain scenarios. This action occurs in a POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomeAction() {
    if( someCondition )
        return RedirectToAction("SomeActionError");

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult SomeActionError() {
    return View();
}
```

Currently I have it set up so that it will redirect to an error controller action. I'm not really fond of this approach because in the URL they see `/SomeActionError` and it also means that the user can directly navigate to this URL.

Is it a bad design/approach to put some flag in TempData and redirect to another controller that checks for the TempData error flag?

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomeAction() {
    if( someCondition ) {
        TempData["DoSomeActionError"] = true;            
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index() {
    // check for error
    if( TempData["DoSomeActionError"] ) {
        return View("SomeActionError");
    }
}
```

Is this a bad idea? Is there another approach that does something similar (doesn't allow the user to directly navigate to the error action)? I don't want to return the View on the POST action because I don't want them to refresh and cause another POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TempData is not per se a bad concept. TempData is for transporting an information to some consumer that reads that information and the information should vanish after it's been read.

The way your're using TempData is odd. A more elegant implementation for your requirements (you should show an error message) is to implement an equivalent to the rails flash concept and don't redirect to an error page but display an error message in your index view. Something like a red banner that says "The record could not be saved".

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581214/flash-equivalent-in-asp-net-mvc-3) shows a nice flash implementation including the view stuff (not the accepted answer but the answer by @jim)

Answer (score 1):

using tempdata in mvc is not a good approach.
If i were you i'll do as following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomeAction() {
   if( someCondition ) {
       return RedirectToAction("Index", new{error=true}           
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index(bool? error) {
    // check for error
    if(error?? false ) {
        return View("SomeActionError");
    }
}
```

Comment: Using TempData in general or using it for this scenario?

Comment: Not really fond of adding a new parameter to my controller action. That seems like a worse approach. I could pass that value in a query string and cause the error page to show.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't agree TempData is always bad (I find it great for status messages I absolutely don't want passed on the url such as "record saved", I think in your case there may be a better option.

First you don't want an error page to be accessible - may I ask why?
To do a redirect when an error happens only to redirect again is a bit odd. I would throw the exception and handle that exception by your error view. MVC automatically adds the **[HandleError]** attribute as a global filter, so throw your exception (a custom type if necessary) and handle it in your error page as you see fit since you can access exception details there and it doesn't require a redirect.

Comment: I'm not redirecting again? It's not an exception error, more like a business rule violation. I have an action on the Index page that will POST to the DoSomeAction method. If the business rules in place determine that the action can't be taken for some reason or another, I want to display the error page. So I originally redirected to an error action, but was wondering if I could just use TempData and redirect back to the Index action (where the call originated from).

Comment: My action basically is kind of doing a workflow action - give me the next item that can be worked. If there are no work items that are left, then I want to display a "There are no more work items left" message.

Comment: Not that there is anything terribly wrong with them navigating directly to the /NoWorkItemsAvailable page, but there is also no good reason for it either.