# Is there a handy Action summary extension method in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP.NET MVC has a handy HtmlHelper extension called ValidationSummary, for when something goes wrong.  It's used like this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Problem. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```

Is there something in the framework to provide feedback to the user when stuff has gone right?  E.g. like "Account Created" or something like that.

Comment: Have you looked at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581214/flash-equivalent-in-asp-net-mvc-3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ViewBag folowing way:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Operation sucessed"; 
    return View();
}
```

And in view:

```
<b>@ViewBag.Message</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `TempData` is designed just for such situations. You use it just like you'd use the `ViewData`, however the value is automatically removed when read for the first time. It means that the notification will be visible only first time the view is rendered.

Also, `TempData` is great because it is persisted between actions. It means that if you redirect to another action (and usually after succesful POST you redirect), the `TempData` is still there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx