# Required an alert of success or failure after form post in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an input box and a html file uploader in my form. I want to submit the text of the input box and uploaded file which will be saved in database and then I need an success or failure alert in my html page. I've no idea how can I do this. I have already done the procedure of getting the post value and save it in database but I can't give any alert to my web page.net mvc3. I am using asp.net mvc3. Any kind of help will be appriciated.

Comment: Are you redirecting after file upload?

Comment: Possibly this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581214/flash-equivalent-in-asp-net-mvc-3 will be helpful

Comment: no i'm not redirecting.I'll remain in same page.

Comment: @user1576559 use $.ajax to post it to the controller and return specific response on failure or success and throw an alert in $.ajax success callback

Comment: Posting files using AJAX is not straight forward. You have to use some jquery plugin.

Comment: Exactly.Using $.ajax the file uploading is not straight forward.But what should i use.Can u tell me properly?

Comment: See this link : http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/ and check the FAQ section. Overall it says they use the hidden IFrame to get this done . I have used this plugin and works good

Comment: Use a notification framework like pNotify: http://sciactive.com/pnotify/

Answer (score 1):

```
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Write
                ("<script>alert('" + pageTable[page].Dequeue() + "');</script>");
```

[see this example this will help you](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/370157/A-Windows-Form-like-MessageBox-for-ASP-NET-Website)

Comment: That I Know how to write alert or msgbox.But my quesion is that when i'll submit a form to a perticular action in a controller  after that how can i generate this alert message from server to my webpage??

Comment: have u seen that link which i post?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MVC , you can have a javascript logic written in the VIEW which will be called only if certain FLAG is true. When you are calling for the first time the view that FLAG will be off . once you have uploaded successfully make that FLAG true which will either execute or write the javascript with alert message on page and will seen by the user